# SerialDevice: DataReader's DetachBuffer - documentation

Tags: c#, uwp

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Streams.IDataReader#Windows_Storage_Streams_IDataReader_DetachBuffer) for DataReader's `DetachBuffer` and `DetachStream` is very vague. It just says `*Detaches a buffer that was previously attached to the reader*'.

**In short**

When should `reader.DetachBuffer();` be used?

**Background**

*Reading*

An example read method for a `SerialDevice` could look something like this:

```
using (var reader = new DataReader(inputStream))
{
    var bytesReceived = await reader.LoadAsync(EXPECTED_RESPONSE_LENGTH);

    var receivedBuffer = new byte[bytesReceived];
    reader.ReadBytes(receivedBuffer);

    reader.DetachStream();
    return receivedBuffer;
}
```

This code works and seems to be stable, but since I write and read multiple times a second on an embedded device I want to avoid creating the `receivedBuffer` buffer each time. I modified my method to be something like the code below.

```
byte[] _receivedBuffer = new byte[EXPECTED_RESPONSE_LENGTH];

private async Task<byte[]> ReadOnceAsync(IInputStream inputStream)
{
    using (var reader = new DataReader(inputStream))
    {
        reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

        uint bytesReceived = await reader.LoadAsync(EXPECTED_RESPONSE_LENGTH);

        var isExpectedLength = (bytesReceived == EXPECTED_RESPONSE_LENGTH);
        if (isExpectedLength)
        {
            reader.ReadBytes(_receivedBuffer);
        }

        reader.DetachStream();
        return isExpectedLength ? _receivedBuffer: null;
    }
}
```

This code crashes my application, sometimes with Access Violation message, within minutes of starting or within seconds if the connected device stops responding.

After I added `reader.DetachBuffer();` the code is stable again, but I still don't know if `DetachBuffer` should be called always, sometimes or not at all.

*Writing*

My write method does not call `writer.DetachStream()` but I don't know if it should or not. The code is:

```
using (var writer = new DataWriter(outputStream))
{
    writer.WriteBytes(toSend);
    var bytesWritten = await writer.StoreAsync();
    //Should writer.DetachBuffer(); be called?
    writer.DetachStream();
    return bytesWritten;
}
```

Comment: To know how much you have left to read, I'd recommend you use the `DataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength` property.

Comment: That *using* statement does not do what you think it does.  A DataReader does not have anything worth disposable or closable.  What it *actually* does is call inputStream.Close().  You can't use it anymore after that, you probably do.  By calling the Detach methods you limit the damage.  The sane way to do this is simply not use *using* or to keep the DataReader object around for as long as the SerialDevice is in use.

Comment: @HansPassant I know you're a guru, but what is your knowledge about this based on?

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue? When I test with your code, it works well in my side. IMHO, there should be no need to use `reader.DetachBuffer();` in your code.